# Python3 Glove Attribute Error: 'generator' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, glove

I am trying to train my model using glove. My code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import pprint
import gensim

from glove import Glove 
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import Sequence
def read_corpus(filename):

delchars = [chr(c) for c in range(256)]
delchars = [x for x in delchars if not x.isalnum()]
delchars.remove(' ')
delchars = ''.join(delchars)

with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        yield line.lower().translate(None, delchars).split(' ')


if __name__ == '__main__':


base_path = "/home/hunzala_awan/vocab.pubmed1.txt"

get_data = read_corpus(base_path)

glove = Glove(no_components=100, learning_rate=0.05)
glove.fit(get_data, epochs=10, verbose=True) 

pprint.pprint(glove.most_similar("cancer", number=10))
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "mytest3.py", line 36, in 
>   glove.fit(get_data, epochs=10, verbose=True) 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/glove/glove.py", line 86, in fit
>   shape = matrix.shape
>   AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'shape'

What am I missing? Any help in this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Glove, but it seems that it can't fit from genberator function. You can try yield it ahead-of-time and convert to list (it will be more memory-consuming):

```
glove.fit(list(get_data), epochs=10, verbose=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did this but now I got new error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest3.py", line 36, in <module>
    glove.fit(list(get_data), epochs=10, verbose=True)
  File "mytest3.py", line 25, in read_corpus
    yield line.lower().translate(None, delchars).split(' ')
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
`